# What are BSDs' equivalents to /proc and /sys?

Tags: linux, proc, bsd, sysfs

The amount of information that can be gathered in linux using the `procfs` and `sysfs` which are normally mounted at `/proc` and `/sys` is quite substantial.

Being not on a FreeBSD install I am amazed to find that neither of those filesystems (and there inforamtion) is availeble. This question seeks as an answer a summary information how those tasks of gathering system inforamtion is supposed to be done in BSD style operation systems in absence of those filesystems

I am aware that I could get some process inforamtion via

```
mount -t procfs proc /proc
```

yet many of the information in that linux has in `/proc` (and which should have been moved to `/sys` I guess is not available anyway).

Comment: What type of info are you looking for? Most can probably be queried via `sysctl`.

Comment: The info is available via the [`kvm(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/kvm.3) and `sysctl(2)` interfaces. They're not identical between different BSDs, and some of the info is not readily available as it's on Linux (eg. on OpenBSD, [`procmap(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/procmap.1) is restricted and cannot be used by default).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what do you want but the command [sysctl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) provides many informations. See [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/procfs.html) too.